# Damaged overhang

Tags: ultimaker-cura, pla, stability

I have issues with this overhang:

[image: Damaged overhang]

The whole part always breaks in this overhang during the print.

I tried to increase the count of wall lines and decrease printing speed, but none of those things help. Do you have any idea how to fix it? Is possible to create support inside a model to print this overhang?

(I´m using Cura 4.1.0.)

I´m using 3 wall´s lines and 15% gyroid infill. My bed has 70 °C and nozzle 205 °C. I am using PLA Prusament galaxy black.  The part is oriented the right way. By overhang I mean damaged part above holes.

Comment: I would imagine the infill handling that, but maybe some number of top layers setting is 1 and the slicer counts those as top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get upwards facing things failing it can be because the slicer has too few top layers which makes angled faces have gaps. While you may think it is a wall the slicer sees it as top layer. Try increasing the number of top layers and check in the preview how it appears.

Infill will normally support those faces so no separate support is needed. Just make sure you have enough top layers that no gaps form, 3-5 layers should be alright.

Answer (score 2):

As @r-ahlskog pointed out, it was due to the top layers count being too low. Adding some, now it looks perfect:

[image]